# How to group rows where one or more columns are equal?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Let's say I have a database of products that have the following columns:

```
name
isbn
ean
upc
sku
```

And I want to group products together if any of those columns match. How can I do that?

I tried using the `GROUP BY` clause, but apparently that means that *all* of the columns have to match, not just a single one.

In other words, `GROUP BY name, isbn, ean, upc, sku` only groups products together when *all* of the columns are equal, where I'm wanting to group them together if *any* of the columns are equal.

**Example:**

```
id  |  name   |     isbn     |  ean  |    upc     | sku
 0    banana1       null        null   0000000000   1234
 1    banana2       6789        null   0000000000   1234 
 2    banana3       6789        null   1111111111   null
 3    banana4       null        null   1111111111   null
```

All of those rows should be grouped together because they have at least one matching column with respect to each other.

Comment: @Wrikken what do you mean by a & b? There's only one table..

Comment: Can you give an example? Input and desired output?

Comment: Example will help. What do you mean by group together?

Comment: Sorry, I'll add an example.

Comment: @Nate . . . This is a graph traversal problem, and MySQL is poorly suited for such tasks.  Perhaps there are other constraints on the problem that make it more solvable.

Comment: @GordonLinoff DO you want to make your comment an answer? After a lot of trying, I think you're right that what I'm trying to do can't be done in a single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a graph traversal problem and painful to implement in SQL -- and especially MySQL which doesn't have support for hierarchical queries.

There is an iterative solution that is not too bad.  The idea is to add a column "groupid" and then continually update.  The rule for the update is to initially populate it with the id and then assign it the minimum along any of the dimensions.  Here is an example of code:

```
update products
    set groupid = id;

/* now run this multiple times until there are no more updates */
update products p
    set groupid = (select min(groupid)
                   from products p2
                   where p.name = p2.name or
                         p.isbn = p2.isbn or
                         p.ean = p2.ean or
                         p.upc = p2.upc or
                         p.sku = p2.sku
                 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Nope. `GROUP BY` requires that all elements in the grouped expression are identical amongst rows in that group. The best I can think of is:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  table
WHERE
  name = isbn 
  OR name = ean
  OR name = upc
  OR name = sku
  OR isbn = ean
  OR isbn = upc
  OR isbn = sku
  OR ean = upc
  OR ean = sku
  OR upc = sku
```

The downside, as you can see, is that this is phenomenally ugly, and doesn't scale well when adding a new column. I would only use this if it was a one-off script--for example, to identify data corruption.

Comment: Isn't that comparing a row against itself, instead of against other rows?

Comment: Yes. I interpreted your question differently from your intent, it seems. An example will definitely help clarify your intent.